# Can't get logo and nav bar in same line in the header

Tags: html, css, header, navigation, nav

I'm sure there is probably a simple solution to this problem but I can't seem to figure this out. I'm in the process of learning front end web development and am building this website just as a project. Anything I've been trying doesn't seem to work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FatHead | Blog</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,500,600,700,800|Muli:400,300italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1 id="logo-large">FAT</h1><h1 id="logo-small">HEAD</h1>
                <div class="nav">
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </body>    
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/***********************************
          LOGO
***********************************/

.header{
background-color: skyblue;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width: 100%;

}

.logo{
text-align: left;
display: block;
margin:0 15px 15px 15px;

}

#logo-large{
display: inline;
font-size: 3em;
font-weight: 200%;
font-family: 'Dosis' , sans-serif;
}

#logo-small{
display: inline;
font-weight:0;
font-size: 3em;
font-family: 'Dosis' ,sans-serif;
}


/************************************
           NAVIGATION
************************************/

.nav ul{
list-style-type:none;
display: block;
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px;
text-align: center;


}

.nav ul li{
display: inline;
padding: 5px 15px;

}

.nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
padding: 5px;
color:black;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.25em;

}

.nav ul li a:active, .nav ul li a:hover{
background-color: deepskyblue;
color: white;
}









body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: the <H1> tag will always be on new line. try this try <h1> <span id="logo-large">FAT</span><span id="logo-small">HEAD</span></h1> there is no need for the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think your mark-up is slightly incorrect for this scenario as you have wrapped your `nav` in the logo `div`. Also, I would suggest adopting HTML 5 standards for your mark-up:

HTML:

```
<header>

    <h1 id="logo-large">FAT</h1>
    <h1 id="logo-small">HEAD</h1>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<header>
```

NAV CSS:

```
nav{
display:inline;
float:right;
}

nav ul{
    list-style:none;
}


nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

See fiddle demo for example: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3340zgxg/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,500,600,700,800|Muli:400,300italic,400italic");
/***********************************
LOGO
***********************************/

.header{
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo{
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  margin:0 15px 15px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#logo-large{
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 200%;
  font-family: 'Dosis' , sans-serif;
  float: left;
}

#logo-small{
  font-weight:0;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: 'Dosis' ,sans-serif;
  float: left;
}


/************************************
NAVIGATION
************************************/

.nav ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}

.nav ul li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 15px;

}

.nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  color:black;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;

}

.nav ul li a:active, .nav ul li a:hover{
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h1 id="logo-large">FAT</h1><h1 id="logo-small">HEAD</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the code below to your CSS.

**CSS**

```
.logo > .nav{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vapyr0t1/)